# VBA Macro is not droping rows with zero values

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, if-statement

I want to drop the rows with zero values in specific columns. However, the macro just works in some rows. I thought that was a format issue so I tried changing the format but it doesn't work. Could you help me find the problem?

[image: Before macro]

[image: After macro]

```
    If IsNumeric(Cells(i, 7).Value) And IsNumeric(Cells(i, 8).Value) And IsNumeric(Cells(i, 9).Value) Then
    Else
    Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next

Worksheets("sheet").Columns("F").NumberFormat = "#,##0.0"
Worksheets("sheet").Columns("G").NumberFormat = "#,##0.0"
Worksheets("sheet").Columns("H").NumberFormat = "#,##0.0"
Worksheets("sheet").Columns("I").NumberFormat = "#,##0.0"

For i = 7 To lastcell
    If Cells(i, 6).Value = 0 And Cells(i, 7).Value = 0 And Cells(i, 8).Value = 0 And Cells(i, 9).Value = 0 Then
    Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next
```

Comment: loop backwards: `For i =  lastcell to 7 Step -1`

Comment: @ScottCraner That was the mistake. Thank you. Could you give me a brief explanation?

Comment: see linked post.  it explains it.

Comment: Note, looping backwards is _one_ solution. A better and much more efficient solution would be to use `Union` to combine the ranges you know you want to delete, and then delete the combined range _once_, after the loop completes: that way you're only hitting the sheet once, and it doesn't matter if you started from the top or from the bottom.